# Disable maven build for particular project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Is it possible to disable **settings.xml** for particular project build using **pom.xml**?
I want to avoid using repositories specified in settings.xml file but only for one project.

Comment: You can use a specific settings.xml as command line parameter for Maven.

Comment: Yes I know --settings flag but in my case I am using parent pom to build modules, and I want to disable repositories from one of them. I wonder if I can do this without changing my build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repositories are defined inside profiles in `settings.xml` file. You can activate and deactivate profiles based on some criteria. See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation) regarding profile activation.

You could:

- deactivate given profile per project by passing `-P !profile-name`
- you could define the profile as

  ```
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>skipThisProfile</name>
      <value>!true</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  ```

  and then run your project with `-DskipThisProfile`
- define the profile as

  ```
  <activation>
    <file>
      <missing>.doNotRunProfile</missing>
    </file>
  </activation>
  ```

  and will not run for any project where there is `.doNotRunProfile` file